# Not able to locate and send data to a web element which is inside a frame which pop ups once button is pressed

Tags: java, iframe, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
 import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
 import org.openqa.selenium.By;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
 import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Iframe {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    WebElement wb;
    try{
    driver.get("http://www.timesjobs.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
    1st Option= Here i assumed that web element is inside the frame which is inside the popup 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    System.out.println("Old window "+driver.getTitle());
    String old=driver.getWindowHandle();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[1][@class='bdr-left']/a")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    for(String newi:driver.getWindowHandles()){
        driver.switchTo().window(newi);}
    System.out.println("New window "+driver.getTitle());
    wb=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='GB_window']/div[2]/iframe"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(wb);
    wb=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='j_username']"));
    wb.click();
    wb.sendKeys("shantanunandan@gmail.com");
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    driver.switchTo().window(old);
    System.out.println("Old window "+driver.getTitle());        

-----------------------------------------------------------------------     
    2nd Option= Here i assumed that web element is inside the frame but in the same webpage
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    wb=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='GB_window']/div[2]/iframe[@id='GB_frame1']"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(wb);
        System.out.println("Frame Name ="+driver.getTitle());
        wb.sendKeys("shantanunandan@gmail.com");

    wb=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='j_username']"));
    wb.click();
    wb.sendKeys("shantanunandan@gmail.com");
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    wb=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ui-accordion-accordion-panel-1']/p"));
    System.out.println(wb.getText());
    Thread.sleep(8000);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    System.out.println("Current Page Is "+driver.getTitle());

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       3rd Option= Here i assume that the button is inside a new pop up window
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  System.out.println("Old window "+driver.getTitle());
    String old=driver.getWindowHandle();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[1][@class='bdr-left']/a")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    for(String newi:driver.getWindowHandles()){
        driver.switchTo().window(newi);}
    System.out.println("New window "+driver.getTitle());
    wb=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='j_username']"));
    wb.click();
    wb.sendKeys("shantanunandan@gmail.com");
    driver.switchTo().window(old);
    System.out.println("Old window "+driver.getTitle());     

 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        }//try
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        driver.close();
        //driver.quit();
    }//catch
    finally{
        driver.close();
        //driver.quit();
    }//finally
}//main
 }//class
```

By the help of above code i am trying to send some data in a webelement names as LogIn. 
So far i tried three way to locate signIn button but all fails by giving me exception NoSuchElement.
When i tried the first logic [1st Option] i got exception NoSuchElement exception
When i tried the second logic [2nd Option] i got exception NoSuchElement exception
When i tried the third logic [2nd Option] i got exception Trying to access element which is inside other frame

Please tell me where i am doing the mistake and how to access the button and send data to it

In the pic the window appers once i clicked the signIn button and the i am trying to send some data inside the Login Id [inside red circle]. Till now i checked the xpaths which i am taking to access the buttons multiple times and they all are correct so there is no chance that i am giving a wrong xpath.

Please tell me where i am doing the mistake and how to access the button and send data to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot of research, I found that there is a `frame` inside a `frame`, and I was trying to access the inner `frame` elements from the outer `frame`. The code which I added to my existing code is below:

```
wb=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='GB_window']/div[2]/iframe[@id='GB_frame1']"));
driver.switchTo().frame(wb);
//This is taking me to outer frame
wb=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='GB_frame']"));
driver.switchTo().frame(wb);
//This is taking me to inner frame which is inside the outer frame
System.out.println("Frame Name ="+driver.getTitle());
wb=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='j_username']"));
wb.click();
wb.sendKeys("sdfs");
```